# How do I make a progress bar?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a progress bar for a product card track so by any click of the user on the prev and next buttons (which would scroll back or forward) the progress bar would advance or backup.
here's the code I came up with. the problem is the first click doesn't show any result and the prev button acts like the next button for the first time. It's like the code is one step behind.
I'm very new to javaScript and I can't figure out how this could happen.

```
const productScroll = () => {

  rightButton.onclick = function () {
   
    let scrollLeft = document.querySelector('#ProductSlider').scrollLeft;
    let scrollPercent = ((scrollLeft - 0) / (5033 - 0)) * (100 - 0) + 0;
    document.querySelector('div.progress-bar').style.width = `${scrollPercent}%`;
    
  };

  leftButton.onclick = function () {

    let scrollLeft = document.querySelector('#ProductSlider').scrollLeft;
    let scrollPercent = ((scrollLeft - 0) / (5033 - 0)) * (100 - 0) + 0;
    document.querySelector('div.progress-bar').style.width = `${scrollPercent}%`;
  };
```

Comment: share some more code to debug your issue with an example including css & html.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is [a native progress bar element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) that might meet your requirements.

Comment: Few questions: where does the `5033` come from, why the `- 0`'s and are you sure `scrollLeft / 5033` ranges between 0 and 1 (so max `scrollLeft` is `5033`)?

Comment: First of all thank you!
the formula was this : new_value = ( (old_value - old_min) / (old_max - old_min) ) * (new_max - new_min) + new_min
I know I didn't have to include 0s but I just wanted to put together the formula
and yes, max scrollLeft is 5033.

Answer (score 1):

If youre always 1 step behind, it could be that your percentage calculation is wrong. For example, if you have 5 steps and want to show progress for each step, starting at 1 and ending at 5, your progress bar needs to have 4 steps instead:

```
1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5 = 4 steps (total - 1)
```

In percentages, it looks like this for a 5 step progress bar:

```
1: 0%
2: 25%
3: 50%
4: 75%
5: 100%
```

Notice each increase is `25%` (1/4) and not `20%` (1/5).

So in abstract shape, your calculation would need to be:

```
((scroll / max) * (steps - 1)) / (steps - 1) * 100%
```

Which means your `scrollLeft  / 5033` needs to be between 0 and 4, divided by 4, then turned into a percentage:

```
const percentage = ((scrollLeft / 5033) * 4) / 4 * 100;
```

Comment: Thank you but It didn't work either.
maybe I wasn't clear with the question before.Let me try again.
When scrollLeft is at 0 and I press the next button for the first time, the bar would not increase but the scrolling occurs. when I press next for the second time, the bar would increase but just as much as it should have increased for the first step and so on.
And when I press the prev button for the first time the bar increases instead of decreasing!
Decreasing happens when I press the prev button for the second time.
I'm sorry, my English is not that good either.

Comment: Is the slider animating to its new position? Cause then it might be using the wrong `scrollLeft` value

Comment: Yes actually It is animating to its new position.
and I do have another problem.
the max scrollLeft changes when the viewport size changes. the code is sloppy.
can you recommend a new approach to this?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML code (better yet, create a fiddle or sandbox) and update your question, so we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

To create a progress bar, first create two “div” tag elements named id `Progress_Status` and `myprogressbar`.

To add a numeric label to indicate how far the user is in the process, the element inside or outside the progress bar is required which will display the progress status which in this case is `myprogressbar`.

```
<div id="Progress_Status"> 
  <div id="myprogressBar">1%</div> 
</div>
```

**Adding CSS:**

```
#Progress_Status { 
  width: 50%; 
  background-color: #ddd; 
} 
  
#myprogressBar { 
  width: 1%; 
  height: 35px; 
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 32px; 
  color: black; 
}
```

**Adding JavaScript:**

Next, Code below creates a dynamic progress bar(animated) using JavaScript functions `update` and `scene`.

```
function update() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");    
  var width = 1; 
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 10); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width >= 100) { 
      clearInterval(identity); 
    } else { 
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
      element.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Firstly, you fetch the element by id and then set starting width to 1. For the purpose of working example, i used `setintervel` to show the progression of progress bar.

All we are doing here is calling the scene function which checks if width is less than 100. If yes, then stop loader by clearing the interval. If not, then increment the width and add it to the with and progress label div for showing the progress in percentenge.

**Complete Code:**

```js
function update() { 
  var element = document.getElementById("myprogressBar");    
  var width = 1; 
  var identity = setInterval(scene, 10); 
  function scene() { 
    if (width >= 100) { 
      clearInterval(identity); 
    } else { 
      width++;  
      element.style.width = width + '%';  
      element.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%'; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

```css
#Progress_Status { 
  width: 50%; 
  background-color: #ddd; 
} 
  
#myprogressBar { 
  width: 1%; 
  height: 35px; 
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 32px; 
  color: black; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<body> 
  
<h3>Example of Progress Bar Using JavaScript</h3> 
  
<p>Download Status of a File:</p> 
  
<div id="Progress_Status"> 
  <div id="myprogressBar">1%</div> 
</div> 
  
<br> 
<button onclick="update()">Start Download</button>  

  
</body> 
</html>
```